# Why does property return null for subclass

Tags: java

Im relatively new to `Java`. I have an issue i cant quite figure out.

I have an abstract class (the super class), with a property, type.

```
public abstract class Variable implements ICompilerObject {

    public String id;
    public Type type;

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Variable(String name, Type t){
        this.id = name;
        type = t;
    }

}
```

I then have some subclasses of type:

```
public class NumberVariable extends Variable {

    public int value;

    public NumberVariable(String name){
        super(name, new NumberType());
    }

}
```

I want to use the type property to get an instance of an object (here it is NumberType(). which is a sublclass of Type.)
Howeever when i print this:

```
Variable var = someFunctionThatGetsAVariableFromList(); 
// var is now a NumberVariable with type == new NumberType();
System.out.println(var.type); //Prints null
System.out.println(var.type.getClass()); 
//Prints class compilerObjects.types.NumberType
```

Im trying to figure why var.type doesn't return the NumberType object.
The problem im trying to solve is:
I need to do some type checking, where 2 objects needs to be compare, to see if they have the same type (that being the same Type object and NOT Java types).
The idea behind the approach above is that i can get the Type object from the property of the object and then compare those. 
I have also tried creating a method instead (implemented on the Variable Subclass):

```
@Override
public Type getType() {
    return new NumberType();
}
```

However this also prints null.

EDIT:
There seems to be some confusion about having both a type property and a getType() method. 
Here is the reason:
They are NOT meant to both be present. They are NOT meant to be related.
This is the two approaches i have tried, but both return null.
The question is not around which approach is better, but rather what causes the mentioned behaviour.

I have updated the code to reflect Thomas's answer

Comment: Here I have used your code (just replace `Type` with `Integer`) and create my own `NumberVariable` instead of your method to do it. As expected, `var.type` return the value set in the constructor of `NumberVariable` and `var.getType` return the value of this method. No null here. Please post a [mcve] to reproduce how you get a null. EDIT : based on your edit, same result but with `type` off course. Same instance.

Comment: "The question is not around which approach is better, but rather what causes the mentioned behaviour." - that's the problem with confusing (and partial) code: it isn't clear what your actual problem is so we can only comment on what we see (e.g. the non-related method and property) or guess on what we don't see. So for future reference please reduce your examples to a minimum but include everything relevant (aka [mcve]). That increases the odds of someone spotting the error dramatically - and while creating the example you might even spot the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code's comment:

```
System.out.println(var.type); 
//Prints null
System.out.println(var.type.getClass()); 
//Prints class compilerObjects.types.NumberType
```

I can assure you that `var.type`. It is not null because the JVM will actually call `var.type.toString()` to print the instance value. So if you check this instance, you should see an override of `toString()` returning `null`.

How can I be sure, well you don't get a `NullPointerException` on the second line, a call of `.getClass()` on a null instance would throw a runtime exception, your code don't.

Just update `Type.toString()` or the subclass `NumberType.toString()` to get the correct value

Comment: This was indeed the issue

Answer (score 1):

In your superclass you have this:

```
public Type type;
public abstract Type getType();
```

That means that `getType()` is an *abstract* method without any implementation and no relation to `type` at all (except for similarities in name).

In your subclass you then *implement* that abstract method and return a new instance of the corresponding type on every call:

```
public Type getType() {
  return new NumberType();
}
```

Again there's no relation to `type` and hence `var.type` will still be null.

Since you're already passing the type to the constructor you probably want to create in implementation of `getType()` in your superclass:

```
public Type getType() {
  return type;
}
```

and remove the overriding implementation in your subclasses.

Also note that `System.out.println(var.type);` might still print `null` even if `type` is not null. That's because `toString()` is called on `type` and if you've overridden that method to return null you'll get null.

An indicator for you doing this is that `System.out.println(var.type.getClass());` doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: This is correct. var.type is set with the constructor. They are not meant to be connected.

Comment: @DJESMOND I'd say that having no connection between `type` and `getType()` is a design error. If they are meant to be different things then the names should reflect that.

Comment: @DJESMOND Then I suggest you to use an other name, `getType` is a standard for the getter of `type` (you will find that standard in every bean and POJO even). If `var.type` is not suppose to be return by this method, rename one.

Comment: I have left both there for testing as im unsure what causes this behaviour.

Comment: @DJESMOND have a look at the last 2 paragraphs I added. If you didn't override `toString()` somehow then we might need more information, ideally a [mcve]. Besides that you should probably step through your code with a debugger and check what's null and why (might have been set to null or not set at all).

Comment: @DJESMOND another note on "They are not meant to be connected": your example suggests that they _are_ connected. In fact you set  `new NumberType()` in the constructor and return the same from `getType()`. Note that this has implications on performance (object creation) and memory (objects take space) and doesn't seem necessary. In fact, in most cases simple types are probably best implemented as enums.

Comment: @Thomas I have updated the code. And it seems that it was indeed an override of ToString() in other part of the code.

Comment: This does solve my problem. I will refactor the code. The problem was that ToString Returned null, while getClass() returned the correct class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use comprator or comparable as per your requirement. these two are best approaches to compare any object in case iterations.
There are lot many utility class in java 8 for compression. 
see below the code what i did which is working a little bit tweaking is required thats it :-)

```
<pre>
    package stackoverflowquestions;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class NumberVariable extends Variable {
        public int value;

        @Override
        public Type getType() {
            return new NumberType();
        }

        public NumberVariable(String name) {
            super(name, new NumberType());
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Variable variable = someFunctionThatGetsAVariableFromList();
            System.out.println(variable.type); // Prints null
            System.out.println(variable.type.getClass());
        }
        private static Variable someFunctionThatGetsAVariableFromList() {
            List<Variable> vl = new ArrayList<Variable>();

            Variable variable = new NumberVariable("new Object");
            vl.add(variable);
            return vl.get(0);
        }

    }
    abstract class Variable implements ICompilerObject {
        public String id;
        public Type type;

        public Variable(String name, Type t) {
            this.id = name;
            this.type = t;
        }
        public abstract Type getType();}

class Type {

}
class NumberType extends Type {

}
interface ICompilerObject {
}
```